# Adobe Illustrator: Can't make a very simple clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

Of course, I'm a total newbie with Illustrator, but as per title I can't get the clipping mask tool to work in this basic situation:

[image]

The dialog says:

> Unable to create a clipping mask. The top selected object should be a path, composite object, text or a group of these elements.

But my top item is a path, made with the pen tool.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No its a group.

Comment: That solved it, so you can't clip inside groups? It always has to be the in the "root" of the project? Or is the problem the fact that the two things in the group were the mask and the image to be masked (would it be fine if there was a third thing in the group, for instance)?

Comment: No the black arrow selection selects the group. Had you actually selected the objects in the group not the group itself with the white or white arrow plus it would have worked.

Comment: Very helpfull, thank you!